# What is the size of a pointer in C? Shouldn't it depend on the operating system your working in? 64-bit vs 32-bit etc

Tags: c, operating-system

I recently came across the question in an interview. "What is the size of a pointer in C?".

My first thought was to ask, "well it depends on the computers operating system whether we are working in 64-bit, 32-bit, 8-bit etc." From my previous knowledge working with C (mostly in python now) I remember that if we are in 32-bit OS then the size of a pointer would be 4 bytes and in 64-bit OS 8 bytes. Can someone elaborate more clearly? or correct me if I am mistaken?

Comment: Yes, it varies between architectures.  Also, on some machines, data pointers and function pointers are different sizes.

Comment: It can very even "on" the same architecture.  For example, I believe that modern versions of Linux and Windows can run both 32-bit and 64-bit executables side by side.

Comment: Note that the IBM iSeries (AS/400, OS/400) machines use 16-byte pointers.  For example, see the discussion in [Chapter 22: Using OS/400 pointers in a program](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_9.5.1/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/cpprog440.htm) and also [Chapter 29: Using Teraspace in ILE C and C++ programs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_9.5.1/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/cpprog588.htm). There are also 8-byte pointer libraries; code compiled for 8-byte pointers can't link with 16-byte pointer libraries and vice versa. (16-byte pointers are 'native'.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The data pointers and function pointers were what I needed to investigate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> the size of a pointer

```
printf("%zu bits\n", sizeof (your_pointer_type_here) * CHAR_BIT);
```

Your could see 16, 32, 48, 64 bit, or  all sorts of other values.  16,32,64 are certainly the most popular.

C allows all sorts of architectures besides "32-bit OS" with 4-byte pointer and "64-bit OS" with 8.  It is compiler dependent influenced by what is possible on a given architecture.

**Size may depend on type**

A function pointer need not be the same size/encoding as a object pointer.

Also a `int *` may differ form a `double *` for example, yet all object pointers convert to/from a `void *` - even when of different sizes.

---

Good code avoid needing to know the size, but adapts as needed.